# Can't open http://www.fictionmania.tv/enter.html

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I am not sure if I am on the correct site but I am at my wits end not being able to read stories from this site: -  http://www.fictionmania.tv/enter.html

I last entered and read from this site 12/04/2013 as from the 13/04/2013 can't seem to access this is it my computer.

Would be very grateful if you would advise ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

The site is offline... Next time just use websites like [Down for everyone or just for me?](http://www.fictionmania.tv/enter.html) or [Is up?](http://isup.me/) to check whether it's just you or the website.